# How retrieve wikipage text in XML format of "text/x-wiki" format

Tags: xml, rest, api, mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

**Question:**

I have been trying to extract wiki page information using the Mediawiki RESTfull API. I seem to retrieve the page text in a "text/x-wiki" format, but I require XML elements if I want to transform the data in Talend.

Is it possible to retrieve Mediawiki query results in a full XML format (so without the text/x-wiki)?

**[Wrong] Example text/x-wiki format:**

```
<format>text/x-wiki</format>
<text xml:space="preserve" bytes="952">
   {{Handelingsperspectief
   |Context=OLmK Naasten - Contact met lotgenoten,
   |Intentional Element decomposition type=IOR
   }}
</text>
```

**[Right] Example XML format:**

```
<format>xml</format>
<text xml:space="preserve" bytes="952">
   <Handelingsperspectief>
    <Context>OLmK Naasten - Contact met lotgenoten</context>
    <Intentional_Element_decomposition_type>IOR</Intentional_Element_decomposition_type>
   </Handelingsperspectief>
</text>
```

**Context/Situation:**

As part of a research for creating a "interactive 3D narrative experience" (a game) that stimulates human understanding, to support solve society problems, there must be extracted wiki content. 
This wiki content comes from a (semantic) Mediawiki. This wiki expresses the Expertise Management ontology (EMont), an ontology for describing human interaction, within certain conditions. The wiki expresses the ontology in an object-oriented paradigm, each page represents an instance of the EMont elements.

Comment: You can use the [parse API endpoint](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext) with `prop=parsetree` to get an XML representation of template parameters, although a significantly less helpful one than the example in the question. (You can probably do better with the semantic query API, I'm not really familiar with it.)

Comment: Thank you, for your helpful answer! 

Sadly, it seems that your right about the "significantly less helpful one". The outputted code becomes harder to extract data from, but it works for removing the wikitext.

Here is just a small part of the output:
&lt;template lineStart=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;title&gt;Include

Comment: It's more readable after decoding HTML entities, but it will basically just give you the "template tree" of the page and does not help with things like template parameter aliases, templates in template parameter values, or templates called from Lua snippets.